# Select record from table where user is the owner of the company

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I have this stupid problem but I cannot find a solution.

I want to select a user from the database that is the owner of a provided company.

So it needs to have `meta_key = 'owner'` and `meta_value = '1'` but it needs also to have `meta_key = 'company'` and `meta_value = 'company_name'`

This is what I came up with and obviously it is not working:

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'owner' 
AND meta_value = '1' 
AND (meta_key = 'company' AND meta_value = 'company_name');
```

This is a screen of the table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a comment, but the meta_key is most likely the column name so this might work:

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM wp_usermeta 
WHERE owner = '1'
AND company = 'company_name';
```

Comment: That doesn't work because `owner` and `company`aren't columns.

Answer (score 0):

How about query like this

```
SELECT
   a.user.id, b.meta_value as company, c.meta_value as owner
FROM
   wp_usermeta a 
   JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.user_id = b.user_id where meta_key=company
   JOIN wp_usermeta c on a.user_id = c.user_id WHERE meta_key=owner
   
WHERE
   company = 'company_name' AND owner='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT uo.user_id
FROM wp_usermeta uo JOIN
     wp_usermeta uc
     ON uo.user_id = uc.user_id
WHERE uo.meta_key = 'owner' AND uo.meta_value = '1' AND
      uc.meta_key = 'company' AND uc.meta_value = 'company_name';
```